# Launching 2 infinite loops in the same time

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a main script in R in a windows Machine that should execute 2 scripts:

- script 1 > check continuously the existence of records of type A in the data base and if there are records, to do transformation and save the data.
- script 2 > check continuously the existence of records of type B in the data base and if there are records, to do transformation and save the data.

I need to manage launching those 2 scripts in the following manner:

- running both of them continuously with no stop to check any new arriving data.

The script is something like:

```
SqlOutputConn_output <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
                                     ,Driver            = driver
                                     ,Server            = server_output
                                     ,Database          = db_output
                                     ,Uid               = user_output
                                     ,Pwd               = pass_output
                                     ,schema           = "exc")
source("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Final Scripts\\STEP 1.R")
source("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Final Scripts\\STEP 1.R")
```

for managing that they keep running, I will use a loop inside each script, but how to launch them in the same time utilizing half of the resources.

Comment: Read about cronjobs for RScripts.

Comment: Readup on the several R packages such as `parallels` which are designed to run tasks in parallel.   Or, depending on your needs,  open a Terminal or cmd.exe (depending on platform) and  run   "R  your_script_1  &" to send the task to the background, repeat for "R your_script_2 &"

Answer (score 0):

You could use asynchronous programming with the help of the `future` package.

A main script runs a loop and waits for each separate script to finish before launching it again after completion :

`main.R`

```
library(future)
plan(multisession,workers=2)

cat("Launch scripts\n")
runScript1 <- future(source('Script1.R'))
runScript2 <- future(source('Script2.R'))

# Set a maximum duration for main script
start <- Sys.time()
maxduration <- 30 # Max duration (s) 

while (difftime(Sys.time(),start) < maxduration) {
  # Wait for completion of Script 1
  if (!resolved(runScript1)) { 
    cat("Script 1 not yet finished\n")
  } else {
    # Print results
    tryCatch({
      result1 <- value(runScript1)
      cat(paste("Script 1 finished at:",result1$value$time,"\n"))
      },error = function(err){ cat("Error in script 1\n")})

    # Launch script again
    runScript1 <- future(source('Script1.R'))
  }
  # Wait for completion of Script 2
  if (!resolved(runScript2)) { 
    cat("Script 2 not yet finished...\n")
  } else {
    # Print results
    tryCatch({
      result2 <- value(runScript2)
      cat(paste("Script 2 finished at:",result2$value$time,"\n"))
    },error = function(err){ cat("Error in script 2\n")})
    
    # Launch script again
    runScript2 <- future(source('Script2.R'))
  }
  # Wait for a while
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

`Script1.R` :

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

# Remove comment below to test error handling
# stop("bug")

Sys.sleep(5)

# Create an ephemeral in-memory RSQLite database
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbTime <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT time('now') time")
dbDisconnect(con)
dbTime
```

`Script2.R` :

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

Sys.sleep(12)

# Create an ephemeral in-memory RSQLite database
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbTime <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT time('now') time")
dbDisconnect(con)
dbTime
```

Result :

```
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 finished at: 18:06:33 
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 finished at: 18:06:38 
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 finished at: 18:06:40 
Script 1 finished at: 18:06:44 
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 finished at: 18:06:49 
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
Script 1 finished at: 18:06:54 
Script 2 finished at: 18:06:53 
Script 1 not yet finished
Script 2 not yet finished...
```